# Is not possible create user when I am deploying MongoDB Kubernetes pod

Tags: mongodb, authentication, kubernetes

I have this deployment and service .yaml for MongoDB in Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo:4.4
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongo-data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        args:
          - --bind_ip
          - 127.0.0.1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-creds
              key: username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-creds
              key: password
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 999
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pvc-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mongo
  name: mongo-nodeport-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and also this Kubernetes secret MongoDB file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: Z1IwUmVyUWlKZ #gR0Rer
  username: QXBp #AUser
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongo-creds
```

When I applied these files and I tried afterwards login to MongoDB pod with encoded user and password:

`mongo --host localhost --port 27017 -u AUser -p gR0Rer`

I wasn't able to login and in log of pod, I found this message:

`{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T12:34:23.630+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn198","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"ApiUser","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"127.0.0.1:54308","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"ApiUser\" for db \"admin\""}}`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating this with the yaml code provided by you and found out that there are encoding problems and you might have overlooked while creating your secret. I have changed the values and it worked for me. I’m attaching the error message for your reference

[image]

If you are still facing issues follow this [documentation](https://devopscube.com/deploy-mongodb-kubernetes/) by Bibin Wilson And Shishir Khandelwal on deploying MongoDB on kubernetes for more information and step by step procedure for deploying your MongoDB on kubernetes.

Comment: @LDonSOvrfw is your issue resolved.. ping here if you need any additional help.